# Resolve Variable in PHP inside MSQL string

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't know what I do wrong inside my code.

I have a mysql database with the table GradDerSchwierigkeitPositiv.

This is the data inside the table:

> [id][text]
>
> [1][$Anr6g waren folgende anspruchsvolle Forschungsaufträge anvertraut]
>
> [...][...]

My PHP code:

```
<?php 
SESSION_START(); 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$Anr6g = $_SESSION["Anr6g"];
echo $Anr6g;
include 'scripts/config.php';
$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$set_utf8 = mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM GradDerSchwierigkeitPositiv";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query1);
include 'templates/header.html';
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo '<select name="list">';
    echo '<option>Select List</option>';
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $text = $row['text'];
        echo "<option value='" . $row["id"] ."'>" . $text ."</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
include 'templates/footer.html'; 
?>
```

The Variable $_SESSION["Anr6g"] is for example "Ihm".

But I don't get the wanted result.

Instead of "Ihm waren folgende anspruchsvolle Forschungsaufträge anvertraut" I get "$Anr6g waren folgende anspruchsvolle Forschungsaufträge anvertraut".

Why?

I don't understand why PHP isn't resolving the Variable correctly.

Thanks you for any tips.

Comment: Because if it expanded everything that would be dangerous. Use `str_replace`. `$text = str_replace('$Anr6g', $Anr6g, $text)`

Comment: Nothing will be resolved in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution

```
preg_match_all('/(?:\$(\w*))/', $text, $b);
foreach ($b[1] as $a) {
$text = str_replace('$' . $a, $$a, $text); }
```

Comment: You should use a template library of some kind, rather than doing dynamic variable replacement like this.